# Can a single unix domain socket connect to multiple peers simultaneously?

Tags: syslog, systemd-journald, unix-sockets, ss

Since this is the socket that `syslog`'s `/dev/log` is symlinked to, I expect there is at least one listening socket from `systemd-journald`, and possibly some additional connected ones, with different "port" numbers. `/run/systemd/journal/stdout` does just that.

Listening socket:

```
# ss -xpl | grep stdout
u_str LISTEN 0      4096                      /run/systemd/journal/stdout 15240            * 0    users:(("systemd-journal",pid=254,fd=5),("systemd",pid=1,fd=38))
```

Connected pair example:

```
# ss -xp | grep 19637
u_str ESTAB 0      0                                         * 20872             * 19637  users:(("dbus-daemon",pid=701,fd=2),("dbus-daemon",pid=701,fd=1))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
u_str ESTAB 0      0               /run/systemd/journal/stdout 19637             * 20872  users:(("systemd-journal",pid=254,fd=73),("systemd",pid=1,fd=78))
```

However for `dev-log`, it seems that there is no listening socket. A single socket("port"=15236) from systemd-journald is connected to multiple peers, and then in its own record, the socket is shown as ESTAB, with the peer "port" shown as 0. How is that possible? Does the unix socket operates fundamentally different in that aspect compared to a tcp one?

Maybe I should ask, what does a port number in `ss` output mean for a unix domain socket?

```
# ss -xpl | grep dev-log
# ss -xp | grep dev-log
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0              /run/systemd/journal/dev-log 15236             * 0      users:(("systemd-journal",pid=254,fd=3),("systemd",pid=1,fd=36))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# ss -xp | grep 15236
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0              /run/systemd/journal/dev-log 15236             * 0      users:(("systemd-journal",pid=254,fd=3),("systemd",pid=1,fd=36))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 19250             * 15236  users:(("dbus-daemon",pid=369,fd=14))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 101364            * 15236  users:(("su",pid=4448,fd=3))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 22068             * 15236  users:(("gdm",pid=373,fd=13))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 20801             * 15236  users:(("(sd-pam",pid=692,fd=8))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 21686             * 15236  users:(("dbus-daemon",pid=701,fd=10))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 19589             * 15236  users:(("gdm-session-wor",pid=680,fd=9))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 104580            * 15236  users:(("sudo",pid=4447,fd=8))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 14305             * 15236  users:(("polkitd",pid=450,fd=10))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
u_dgr ESTAB 0      0                                         * 23001             * 15236  users:(("gnome-session-b",pid=727,fd=17))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev/log` file is `u_dgr` or unix datagram; these do not require a
"listen" as is done for streams (the `u_str` or unix stream of
`/run/systemd/journal/stdout`, which is listening). Datagram servers
only require a socket/bind/recvfrom sequence of calls (and a little
more), while a stream server would need to perform
socket/bind/listen/accept (and a lot more).

> Does the unix socket operates fundamentally different in that aspect compared to a tcp one?

A unix domain *stream* socket operates like TCP. A unix domain *datagram* socket operates like UDP. Unix domain sockets however have pipe-like aspects: unix datagram sockets tend to not have data loss and out-of-order delivery issues like UDP does, for example. But the listen (for streams) or not (for datagram) aspect is the same between unix domain sockets and internet sockets.

> Maybe I should ask, what does a port number in ss output mean for a unix domain socket?

It is probably a magic integer invented by the kernel to identify particular sockets and probably not very important given that unix domain sockets are either internal to processes (like pipes are) or are exposed via the filesystem. In either case nothing needs to know the magic number of the domain socket to use it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I realized dev-log is a datagram socket after posting, but it still puzzles me. Since journald is listening to dev-log for incoming messages, it would calling something like recvfrom() on that socket, without destination address specified, and indeed dest address shows as '*' by ss, all good. But why the status is not UNCONN as in UDP, but a ESTAB in this case?

Comment: And, for the line that shows the dbus-daemon process, the state is ESTAB, but the addresses for both source/local and dest/peer are '*'. I assume ESTAB for a datagram socket means a process is calling recvfrom() with a specific dest address. If so, how can both source and dest address be unnamed? I mean, how can a message be delivered with endpoint's address, which is the only identifier, unspecified? Does unix sockets depend on some other things like the magic number you mentioned?